# Can I resolve dependency from /lib folder? [Maven]

Tags: maven

Today I was trying to "sell" Maven to my project team but came across this use case scenario that stumped me.

The user wishes to store the project's dependencies in the /lib folder and have its dependencies resolved from that folder.

I would like to know if that is quite possible. They do not want to maintain an artifact repository server.

Comment: Thats simply the wrong way. Best is start using a repository Manager which will help in many way. If you hav the deps in lib folder this is nit much improvment from ant etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by setting the decencies with the scope `system`, for example

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>something</groupId>
  <artifactId>something</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${build.dir}/lib/library.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I had to use this in the past, when using commercial jar files, and the client I was working for didn't allow commercial jars to be put in the internal nexus repository.

As @cowls mentioned, not using the dependency management in Maven is removing a big part of the benefit of using it, but not all. You can still use all the testing, reporting and release plugins.

By the way, I can't believe that there are Java projects out there not using Maven or Ivy. Good for you Chin, bad for your team.

Comment: Thanks Augusto. I think you really have what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: It worked. I am just curious, if i use system scoped dependency, then wouldn't what i insert for groupId / artifact / version become redundant?

Comment: yes, they are redundant, but maven expects those xml elements, otherwise it fails to validate the pom. And this is why you lose the dependency management benefit from maven.

Answer (score 2):

The question is why would the user want to store the projects dependencies in a /lib folder?

Dependency management is a large part of Maven, using an artifact repository allows you to include the library as a dependency and only have to manage one instance of the JAR. If you have ten projects referencing a JAR then having to maintain that JAR in all those ten projects would mean 10 JAR files in the /lib project folders.

Bit of a nightmare if you want to upgrade the JAR file.

Unfortunately if you want to use maven and get all the benefits then an artifact repository is the way to go.

---

Example

There is a project library called common.jar. Which is used by project A, B and C

I create a new project. If I want to include common.jar in my project, most likely I go to project A, B or C and copy and paste the JAR. (Not a particurlarly reliable method)

If I have a maven repository I simply add a dependency to the pom

```
<dependency>
    <group>com.example.group</group>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This means there is one central version of the library that all projects will use. You can even declare this in a parent pom and have it included in all projects.

Comment: I agree with you very much. I am less supportive of this notion. I would not recommend this, but I would like to know if it is at all possible because in Graddle this has been done.

Comment: Looks like augusto has provided a potential soluiton. Though you get extra points if you can convince your team to use an artifact repository as well! good luck